# How to upload an image / file using Firebase Realtime database and React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, upload

I'm developing a React Native project and I'm using the Firebase Real-time database for that.

I want to maintain a user profile page. For that, I need to upload a user profile image to the Firebase database. When I view the user profile, I should be able to see the user profile with the relevant user profile image. I should be able to update and remove the user profile image as well.

**Using GCS (Google Cloud Storage) to store the image/file and using Firebase Realtime database to store the URL is also OK for me.**

**I just need the best possible solution.**

I went through some similar questions and still confused about a clear way of doing that.

Can you please explain and tell me how to do this in React Native?

Comment: Sounds like you want to save the image data in Firebase Real-time database instead save the image in GCS (Google Cloud Storage)?

Comment: @ChouW No matter it is Firebase Real-time database or GCS. I just want to achieve above thing. For that, I want the best solution. If Firebase -Real-time database is more suitable and more easy to handle in uploading images, then it's ok for me. If GCS is suitable and better, it's ok for me. Hope you understand what I want.

Comment: I think the best solution is store image file in GCS and store the image URL in Firebase Real-time database.

Comment: @ChouW Got it! So, can you please post the answer on how to do it? I need help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to share some code in my side project, which implemented the features you mentioned above. However, I am sorry that the full access of the project's source code is unavailable.

Step 1. Upload the image file while user submit image.

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const upload = async (filepath: string, filename: string, filemime: string) => {
    const metaData = { contentType: filemime };
    const res = await firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`gcs-folder-name-here/${filename}`)
        .putFile(filepath, metaData); // put image file to GCS
    return res;
};
```

Step 2. After the called the `upload` function you should be able to retrieve the image URL from response and save it back to Firebase Real-time Database.

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
const res = await upload(`absolute/path/to/image.JPG`, `image.JPG`, `image/jpeg`); // function in step 1
const data = {
    name: 'User Name'
    photo: res.downloadURL, // retrieve image URL
};
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set(data);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! I will try out this and let you know... Hope this will work for me as well. :)

Comment: Can you please give me further info about the diference `filepath` and `filename` ? `filename` is the source of the image?

Comment: I updated the post to clarify the different. If there still seems ambiguous, please let me know.

Comment: @willisc I think the args & params are not in same order, correct usage should be like this: `const res = await upload('absolute/path/to/image.JPG', 'image.JPG', 'image/jpeg'); `

Comment: @MohsenVahabzadeh thank you, I updated the order as you mentioned.